# How to encrypt header files in C

Tags: c

We need to have a good way to encrypt our C source. We need the header files to be unreadable by the another one (Codevision or Winavr Compiler).

For example I Drived One GSM Module For Send And recive SMS ... But I need no anyone access to my source and only can use them .. Is there any solution to this problem?

How Can I Make a Compiled Header File ???

Comment: Please Don't Capitalize All Words. It's Painful To Read.

Comment: I tried to fix the question but I don't know what "Header File Unreadable In C" means (I guessed it was related to the compiler but I may be wrong). The question still needs some clarifications.

Comment: If the file is Unreadable by Compiler, it won't compile ever and won't make bin of it! So Why you want to do it?

Comment: @dystroy I think capitilizing each word is an OCD. I find your comment a bit offensive... :)

Comment: "encrypt" source is probably the wrong way to go. Don't release sources and keep them clean and readable.

Comment: Is this scorn really necessary? It's quite clear OP needs much "help", perhaps he/she is not ready to ask a [good](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) question on SO yet. Why not point that out, and help with resources/links instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encrypt your source with any good encryption tool, of course.
**But obviously you can't compile it anymore ...**

But perhaps a library could help you.
You can build a library which contains your GSM stuff.

Then you and others can call the functions from the library, the only file you have to distribute, is the *.h file where the declarations are.

Comment: Erasing them seems more powerful.

Comment: This type of question normally indicates that the source is also at an extremly high level, so that nobodoy want's to see the code (even the compiler)